# Can't save a contact picture for a new contact using Phonegap

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am trying to save a new contact to the phone using Phonegap Contact and it works just fine. However, when I try to add an image, nothing happens. I can't add pictures to the new created contact. So everything works fine but not the picture.

I use this code to add a picture to the Contact object:

```
var photosArray = [];
photosArray[0] = new ContactField('url', 'images/icon.jpg', true);
contact.photos = photosArray;
```

I use same syntax and method to add all the other info like phone number and email and it works.

Any suggestions or ideas would help.

Comment: Never did. I ended up just adding a contact without an image :/

Comment: Nooooo :'( I was going to look for a solution on the web, this discourage me a lot :/

Comment: Well, it might work on new versions of Phonegap. You never know.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the type to "photo" and note what the [documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_contacts_contacts.md.html#ContactField) says about the URL or base64-encoded image string.

```
"photos": [{
     "type": "photo",
     "value": "http://example.com/image.png",
     "id": 0,
     "pref": true
}]
```